I'm new to Django, there is a warning but i can‘t solve it
warningpng
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import ArticlePost
def article_list(request):
    articles = ArticlePost.objects.all()
    context = {'articles': articles}
    return render(request,'article/list.html',context)

# warning is:Class 'ArticlePost' is an unresolved feature reference for the 'objects'

besides, models.py and setting.py are followed:
models.py](https://i.sstatic.net/UDrgP.png) [setting.py`
Looking forward to your help.
I ran python manage.py check ,terminal display "System check identified no issues (0 silenced)."

This is just PyCharm that does not undestand Django's metaprogramming logic.

This is just PyCharm that does not undestand Django's metaprogramming logic. Indeed, Any subclass of a Model (that is not abstract) contains a manager named objects, if you don't specify a manager manually. But this is done through the ModelBase metaclass [GitHub]:

    def _prepare(cls):
        # …
        if not opts.managers:
            manager = Manager()
            manager.auto_created = True
            cls.add_to_class("objects", manager)

But this is often a bit too much for a simple IDE, that thus fails to understand the metaprogramming, and therefore some IDEs and code validators will report a warning or error that the class has no attribute named .objects.
There are linters like pylint-django [pypi.org] that include rule to reason about this. Additionally, PyCharm has a paid version that includes Django support that has added extra rules that allows the IDE to reason about Django models.
